# ¿Cómo exportar archivos de forma asincrona en NODE.JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

He estado viendo en diferentes foros y documentos que se usa fs.readirSync para crear un cargador en node.js, esto para exportar todos los archivos que pueden estar en una carpeta. pero como puedo hacer esto de forma asíncrona, ya que el sync   puede bloquear el event loop.

Esto lo uso para solo llamar a la carpeta donde esta el cargador, ya que este cargador esta en el index.js y este me pasaría todos los archivos exportados a cualquier controlador, el cual esta requiriendo 1 o más archivos de esta carpeta.

No se si se puede hacer, o sea una mala práctica, etc..

Este es el código del cargador:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// esto carga de forma síncrona los archivos de la carpeta.
const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
   return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
})

// esto exporta los archivos.
let fileName = null
files.forEach((file) => {
 fileName = path.basename(file,'.js')
 if (fileName !== 'index')
 {
  exports[fileName] = require('./'+fileName)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Por cada metodo sincrono existe un asincrono, esto para estar de diez sería usando promesas pero dado a tu conocimiento lo hare con callbacks, pero esto habría que hacerlo con promesas.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// esto carga de forma syncrona los archivos de la carpeta.
fs.readdir(__dirname,function(err, files){
    if(!err){
    files.filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
        }).forEach((file) => {
       fileName = path.basename(file,'.js')
       if (fileName !== 'index')
       {
        exports[fileName] = require('./'+fileName)
       }
      });
  }else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Esto sería para un 10:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

function readDirFilesOnlyJS(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    fs.readdir(path,(err, files) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
      resolve(files);
    });
  }).then((files) => {
    return files.filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
        });
  });
};

readDirFilesOnlyJS(__dirname).then((files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
       fileName = path.basename(file,'.js')
       if (fileName !== 'index'){
        exports[fileName] = require('./'+fileName)
       }
   });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("ha habido un fallo")
});
```